# Splliting rows in spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

suppose i have dataset like

```
Name   | Start_Year| End_Year
Steven | 1995      | 1999
Ema    | 2000      | 2004
Hope   | 2005      | 2006
```

The output should be like:

```
Name   | Year 
Steven | 1995
Steven | 1996
Steven | 1997
Steven | 1998
Steven | 1999
Ema    | 2000
Ema    | 2001
Ema    | 2002
Ema    | 2003
Ema    | 2004
Hope   | 2005
Hope   | 2006
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UDF to turn the start and end years into an array of all the years in the range, and then use `explode` to turn each item in that array into a row:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val toRange = udf { (y1: Int, y2: Int) => (y1 to y2).toArray }

input
  .withColumn("years", toRange($"Start_Year", $"End_Year"))
  .select($"Name", explode($"years") as "Year")
```

Comment: I've null values also in my dataframe. It is showing NumberFormatException, can you suggest something here ??

Comment: Which column is null? And what would you like the result to include for these null values? You can either filter them out (using something like `filter($"Start_Year" isNotNull)`), or make the UDF check for null values and return `Array(null)` for such cases

Comment: null values are not in the "Name" but some other column, say, subject. 
I just want to ignore them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ignore", and anyway this is a separate question, I doubt I'll be able to help via comments only, sorry... you can post another question (with a clear input / expected / tried...) or search for existing ones